# Which file format should I use for LaTeX documents in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

TeXShop gives me the option of LaTeX (with a `.ltx` file extension), but the sample LaTeX document I've started to learn with has a `.tex` extension.

It all seems to work fine - does it matter?

(I'm new to this and have only made a few documents in LaTeX. )

Comment: `.ltx` is rather unusal for normal user documents -- the `latex.ltx` format is the core file and in my opinion, the `.ltx` extension should be used for classes and special core stuff, not for user files. You should stick to `.tex` for normal documents

Comment: Thanks - but your answer seems in conflict with your comment.

Comment: No, it doesn't -- You can use `.ltx` for normal documents,but it's unusual. There's no law to use it or to stick to `.tex` extension

Comment: while using `.ltx` for normal user documents, there *is* one environment in which it's a useful practice -- when a collection comprises elements prepared with different flavors of tex, using `.tex` for plain tex files and `.ltx` for latex files identifies the flavor of each file clearly and unambiguously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bunch of core `.ltx` files of TeXLive 2015, none of them refers to a personal, document-level `LaTeX` but to main features of the LaTeX language.

It is of course not forbidden to use `.ltx` as an extension for personal LaTeX files. The compilers treat them correctly.

In my point of view, the question is like in C++: Should one use `.cc` or `.c++` or `.cpp` extensions? All are possible.

The `documentation` tree has some more `.ltx` files.

```
./platex/base/platex.ltx
./platex/base/plcore.ltx
./platex/base/pldefs.ltx
./uplatex/base/uplatex.ltx
./uplatex/base/uplcore.ltx
./uplatex/base/uplpatch.ltx
./uplatex/base/upldefs.ltx
./jadetex/base/jadetex.ltx
./latex/base/fontmath.ltx
./latex/base/fonttext.ltx
./latex/base/preload.ltx
./latex/base/latex.ltx
./latex/base/hyphen.ltx
./latex/hyperref/hylatex.ltx
./latex/carlisle/mylatex.ltx
```

Do not use the `.dtx` extension as this stands for `documentated latex source` file is meant for generating documentation of package/class files basically.