# Standard Extension for a LaTeX File? (or any other variant for that matter)

Tags: latex-misc

I was just wondering what the standard extension is for a LaTeX file. Obviously LaTeX files are just text and therefore the file could be named anything, but I am interested in convention. `myfile.tex` or `myfile.latex` would be two options I would consider to be most obvious. Which is better or is there something else?

Comment: `.tex` is the standard extension.

Comment: It is always `.tex`, never seen otherwise.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! This doesn't cause confusion between LaTeX and plain TeX? I know c++ generally has a modified extension so I was just wondering.

Comment: Not at all.  A latex file has a precise structure, and if you try to compile it with plain TeX, the compiler will scream, and conversely.

Comment: @Bernard I see your point. Just interesting that a c compiler would scream at c++ as well and they also chose a new extension. Seems that they just opted for different conventions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281846/which-file-format-should-i-use-for-latex-documents-in-texshop (the question mentions the TeXshop editor but the answer/discussion is valid nonetheless).

Comment: for tugboat, where we can have plain tex, latex, and context files for the same issue, we use `.tex`, `.ltx`, and `.ctx` respectively.  however, there's always human control over these; the tex program assumes `.tex` as the default, regardless of the tex engine or format being used.

Comment: You can use `.foo` but then you have to use `\input{file.foo}`. If you want `\input{file}` to work then it has to be `.tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard extension for a TeX file is independent of the engine used. See, for example, the output when using typing `tex --help` from the terminal:

```
./>tex --help
Usage: tex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: tex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: tex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
[snip]
```

...and for `latex --help`:

```
./>latex --help
Usage: pdftex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
[snip]
```

...and for `xelatex --help`:

```
./>xelatex --help
Usage: xetex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: xetex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: xetex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
[snip]
```

...and for `lualatex --help`:

```
./>lualatex --help
Usage: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: luatex --lua=FILE [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
[snip]
```

All of the engines use an optional `[.tex]` file extension in their input. That is, it is expecting a `.tex` extension, making it in the standard/default.

Comment: does this mean a `*.latex` extension will be converted to a `*.tex` extension?

Comment: @naphaneal: No. It just means that you don't have to specify the extension if it is `.tex`. If it's `.latex`, then you'll have to specify it. Moreover, (La)TeX does not alter the input, just the output.